# builder pattern json deserialize

Tags: java, json, builder

I have a problem. I just used the example of jackson json for deserializing builder pattern but I always get an empty json. 
I use jackson-databind version 2.8.4
Am I missing something?
So my code is as follows:

The Value class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@JsonDeserialize(builder=ValueBuilder.class)
public class Value {
   private final int x, y;
   protected Value(int x, int y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }
}
```

The ValueBuilder Class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;

//@JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "build", withPrefix = "with")
public class ValueBuilder {
   private int x;
   private int y;

   // can use @JsonCreator to use non-default ctor, inject values etc
   public ValueBuilder() { }

   // if name is "withXxx", works as is: otherwise use @JsonProperty("x") or @JsonSetter("x")!
public ValueBuilder withX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
    return this; // or, construct new instance, return that
}
public ValueBuilder withY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
    return this;
}
@JsonCreator
public Value build() {
    return new Value(x, y);
  }
}
```

The Start Class

```
public class Start {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       Value newValue = new ValueBuilder().withX(2).withY(4).build();
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       String jsonString =  mapper.writeValueAsString(newValue);
       System.out.println(jsonString);
     }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted...

Comment: A Deserializer would be used with .readValue* you're calling .writeValue* which would need a Serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only missing accessible getters for `x` and `y` in your `Value` class - the `ObjectMapper` requires access to those in order to serialize.

Add the following to your `Value` class definition:

```
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;   
}
```

No need for additional annotations in this context.

Your JSON will print out like:

```
{"x":2,"y":4}
```

You could also make the fields `public` to reach the same result, but that would defile proper encapsulation.

Comment: But the approach of the builder pattern is not to have setters in the value class, isnt it? Therefore the jackson lib has since the 2.x version the support for builder pattern with the Annotation "@JsonDeserialize(builder=ValueBuilder.class)" or if I would have different "setters" in the builder class, with other prefix than "with" I'd need to annotate the builder with "@JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "build", withPrefix = "set")".

Comment: It works now. Both ways, to serialize and deserialize. I added getters in the Value class as you said and did some annotations in the builder class. My use case was to have some attributes, which are optional like x is always need and y is optional. Therefore I added: private @JsonProperty("y") int y; and in the builder constructor: public ValueBuilder(@JsonProperty("x") int x) { this.x = x; } And also deleted the builder setter method for x, because x is now always needed when creating and conf. for ObjectMapper: mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);